# Django ManyToMany FIeld: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django, django-models

Having a little django problem i'm stuck with...
My Model:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    [...]
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

My attempt to create a new user on it

```
mymodel = Mymodel.objects.get_or_create(date=date, day=day, time=time) # This one gives a solid Mymodel object i can play with
mymodel.user.add(user) # User is a instance of the Django User System
```

When trying to execute, it throws **'tuple' object has no attribute 'user'**

Did i accidentally turn it into a tuple?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`get_or_create` returns a tuple consisting of (object, created). To get just the model, use:

```
mymodel, _ = Mymodel.objects.get_or_create(date=date, day=day, time=time)
```

or

```
mymodel = Mymodel.objects.get_or_create(date=date, day=day, time=time)[0]
```